# POST Route (via form) Vs. GET Route (post via URL Params)

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I never understand **these 2** completely, can someone **please** put an end to this ?

I have 2 routes :

1- `Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard');`

2- `Route::post('/admin/dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard_post');`

---

If I do this

`{hostname}/admin/dashboard?test=123`

My first route should trigger.

If I create a form, with 1 input and submit the form to `/admin/dashboard`

My second route should trigger.

---

What is different between these 2 POST ?

Are they behaving the same thing ?

How would one know to use one over the other ?

Answer (score 1):

Its basically a matter of what they are used for. If you want to e.g. create something new or upload a file you should use a `POST` request. If you want to *get* Information from the Server, which is already there (e.g. data from a database) you should use `GET`.

To sum it up in short: Use `POST` for **sending** data and `GET` to **receive** data from the server.

For your form: you have to specify which request method should be used:

```
<html>
  // Use GET
  <form action="form.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  // Use POST
  <form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify in your form whether it's submitting a GET or a POST request.

`<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">` will send a GET request and trigger the first route.

`<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">` will send a POST request and trigger the second one.

[More about the difference between get and post.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)